# Include Day-Of-Week in time-related hover-text

Tags: feature-request, tooltips, timestamps

Many places in Stack Exchange include timestamps for events, the time posts were created, commented on, edited, answered, etc.

When you 'hover' over those times, it gives a 'tooltip' indicating the exact time (in UTC) that the event occurred.

For example - hovering over the `asked 2 hours ago` you get the time:

[image]

Often, when timestamps are relatively far in the past, it is very hard to mentally calculate the day-of-week.

**Occasionally it is necessary (especially as a site moderator) to know whether something happened on a Wednesday, rather than a Sunday.**

Adding the day-of-week to the tool-tip would be a simple change but would add a significant amount of value:

```
Mon 2015-01-26 09:22:17Z
```

Comment: Because that time is listed in UTC, the associated day of the week may be different from the one you were in when the event happened, so adding it to the timestamp may add confusion.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - The Day-of-week would obviously match the UTC timestamp, I cannot see how adding the day would compound, or add any more confusion than simply being in UTC already does. (I personally like the UTC timestamps, but I think I am the minority).

Comment: rolfl, I think of day of the week as a concept more tied to subjective experience than the date/timestamp. Why would one want to know what day of the week it was, other than to relate it to something locally-relevant, like whether the author was likely at work? If you see a raw timestamp with a 'Z' at the end, you're more likely to make the necessary conversion. If you see a timestamp that says "Mon 2015-01-26 09:22:17Z," you might just think "oh, Monday morning -> work," and stop there, less likely to consider the fact that the author is in, say US PST and was hacking at 2 am on a Sunday.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - I can appreciate that you may not find the day useful, but that does not mean it is useless for everyone else too. Your issue with the feature seems to be purely: "I can't think of a use therefore no-one else should find it useful either". There are multiple ways this feature could be useful, including some ways related to site moderation, as well as question activity tracking.

Comment: rolfl, my point is not that it wouldn't be useful. I certainly can see the usefulness, e.g. in the case in my example. My point is that, from a UI point of view, adding this information may be misleading in a way that the current format is not.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Why is the current format also not misleading in the same way? Since you are likely to be in another timezone when anything is posted...

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg, as I said above, day of the week is more of a locally-oriented convention than raw date/time is. It's similar to if the timestamp included "morning," or "evening." These extra descriptors would be 100% correct for Greenwich, but their addition would be misleading, because they'd make the reader less prone to realize that the timestamp is UTC and not local.

Comment: @IsaacMoses The timestamp already includes a kind of morning/evening though, `2015-01-26 08:42:53Z` == "Morning". The day of the week itself is as much of a locally-oriented convention as the date itself is. The `Z` in the end is still there, no matter if it says the day of the week in the beginning or not.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Right. "Monday" and "Morning" add nothing logically. What they do is provide redundant, human-oriented information that is, however, only 100% valid for humans in the same time zone as Greenwich. I am suggesting a UI issue with this proposal, not a logical one.

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/72641/when-should-day-of-week-be-included-in-a-timestamp

Answer (score 5):

Here's a userscript implementation: [Timestamps with a day](https://stackapps.com/questions/6138/timestamps-with-a-day)

Requires Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey.

Install the script from [here](https://github.com/Elusive138/SEDayTimestamp/raw/master/SEDayTimestamp.user.js).

If you prefer local time, simply remove the `date.utc()` line and change the format string as desired (remove the `[Z]`).

Comment: Oh, pretty, that works well, installed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution is.

Don’t change the hover text.  But add the day in local time to the “asked 2 days ago” texted.    So show “asked 2 days ago (Web)” or “asked Mon Mar 6 '13 at 12:24”
I don’t need to know if day if it is less than 24 yours ago, or yesterday.